# How to add a method like num.tf(n) as an alias for num.toFixed(n)

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

I'd like to add an alias tf() for methods like toFixed() on the Number type. Example:

```
let num = 1.234;
console.log(num.toFixed(1));  // prints 1.2
console.log(num.tf(2));       // should print 1.23
```

From a bit of research this may be possible but not conventional. I'm just interested in trying it in a private tool, and learning more about Prototype etc, appreciate if you don't reply with a sermon :=)

Many thanks.
GE.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Our program, who art in memory,
    called by thy name;
  thy operating system run;
thy function be done at runtime
  as it was on development.
Give us this day our daily output.
And forgive us our code duplication,
    as we forgive those who
  duplicate code against us.
And lead us not into frustration;
  but deliver us from GOTOs.
    For thine is algorithm,
the computation, and the solution,
    looping forever and ever.
          Return;

Comment: Jared, good call !

Comment: Ok everyone, now I have the answer, you can let rip with the sermons! There are words in the reference sites that you shouldn't mess with fundamental datatypes like Number. I can see that, but for a personal tool that only one person will use, it seems ok. (Sermon: a personal tool could escape and become widely used. Then your Number.personalMethod() could clash with some other method. I guess.)

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for the accurate answers to my question. I will try to close this off now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new prototype named tf in `Number`.

`Number.prototype.tf =Number.prototype.toFixed`

should do it Barmar posted in the answer above.

Although if you are feeling adventerous, you can create a new function to see how this fully works.

```
Number.prototype.tf=function(num){
    return parseFloat(this.valueOf().toFixed(num))
}
```

Both of them do essentially the same thing but the first answer is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign to the `Number` prototype

```js
Number.prototype.tf = Number.prototype.toFixed;
let num = 1.234;
console.log(num.toFixed(1));  // prints 1.2
console.log(num.tf(2));       // should print 1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to properly close this off and mark it answered. Thanks for the excellent answers provided. I won't repeat them here, they're all very clear above. Ciao, Greg E.